# How can I syntax-highlight a function like a macro?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, colors, elisp-macros

I've got a function that behaves more like a macro in that it does compile-time environment definitions.  For various reasons (at this point, one of those reasons is 'because it is easier to grok in my head'), I'd like to keep it as a function.  When I use the function, how can I have emacs color it like it would a macro?

```
(defun test-func ())
(defmacro test-macro ())

(test-func)  ; not colored
(test-macro) ; colored
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you want to better understand why this is the default behavior, or perhaps you want a simpler solution, but here is at least one quick solution:

Load library [**`hl-defined`**](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/hl-defined.el) and turn on minor mode `hdefd-highlight-mode`. To get exactly the same face for functions as you see for `test-macro`, customize face `hdefd-functions` to be the same as (i.e., just inherit from) face `font-lock-keyword-face`.

(If you don't want to also highlight *variables*, customize option `hdefd-highlight-type` to just the value `functions`.)

Comment: Why is that the default behaviour? Please enlighten us!

Comment: @Dox: I don't know why. That sentence was just to say that my answer might not be responding to what the OP really wants, which I'm guessing is to better understand the default font-locking or how to tweak it to get (only) what he wants as a slight modification. My answer provides, I think, the behavior requested, but I suspect that the behavior is less the point than is understanding how to get what OP wants.